# Why echo after printf is not displaying in a new line?

Tags: bash, echo, newlines, printf

I have a code which will use `printf` and then `echo` command. As per my understanding `echo` will by default come in new line, but not happening when it is used after `printf`. Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function login
{
  printf "\n%s" "Please enter ${1} password: "
  read -s passcode
}
for i in root admin; do login $i; done
echo "just something"
```

In this code `"\n%s"` is important as I might be using multiple users in that loop. The output is like below:

```
[root@host ]# /tmp/test.sh

Please enter root password:
Please enter admin password: just something
[root@host ]#
```

I know by putting a `echo ""` after the loop will simply fix and create a new line, but I would like to know why while looping with `printf` it's working and why not with `echo` afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` outputs a newline at the end of the string, not at the beginning.

`printf` interprets `\n` as a newline, but `\n%s` prints the newline before the rest of the output, not after it.

And since with `read -s`, we suppress the terminal local *echo* of what is being typed, when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that also suppresses the CRLF *echo*.

In any case, the syntax to read the password should be `IFS= read -r passcode`, or it wouldn't work properly if the password contained backslash or `$IFS` characters.

Comment: With `bash`, use `read -p 'some prompt'` to provide a prompt for the user. The script in the question prints the prompt to standard output. Interactive prompts should be printed to standard error, which `read -p` does.  Also, `login` is a poor choice of name for the function as it 1) does not log in, and 2) it overrides the existing `login` utility's name.

Comment: @Kusalananda the name login was just a testing one, I usually name my functions starting with `f__`. Thanks!